# sql in php file works when run in browser, but not when run from command line

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, command-line

I've been trying to figure this out for 2 days. Here's the scenario:

a function in notificaton_system.php runs, and if certain conditions are met, it runs this:

```
$cmd = 'php -f /var/www/site.com' . $system_file . ' /file:"' . $file . '" /environment:"' . $application_env . '"';

$update_data = exec($cmd, $out, $retvar);

return $update_data;
```

inside $system_file, it has this sql statement called using PDO:

```
$sql = '
update
    `USER`.t_pto_request
    set status_code = :pto_status
where 
    request_id = :update_id;
';
```

after this statement runs, I have it echo out errors:

```
$error_arr = $stmt->errorInfo();
print_r($error_arr);
```

it always shows no errors:

```
Array(
    [0] => 00000
    [1] =>
    [2] =>
)
```

it then selects the row and echos it out:

```
$sql_2 = '
select 
    request_id,
    user_id,
    status_code
from
    `USER`.t_pto_request
where
    request_id = :update_id;
';
```

however, the row is NOT updated (I have tested many times), and it always echos out an empty array when it tries to select the row it was supposed to update.

if I run the **exact same** program directly in the browser and pass in the values through the querystring instead of command line arguments:

```
https://www.oursite.com/path/to/file/system_file.php?file=/path/to/sys_file.txt&environment=dev
```

it **does** work and the row is updated. It's using the exact same MySQL user in both cases (run directly in browser vs. run from command line from another PHP program).

I get no PHP or PDO errors in either case

I can't figure out why the statement would return no errors but not update the row when run as a command line program

I realize this is a complicated scenario - Please let me know if I need to post additional information to clarify anything.

Comment: Why do you run PHP from the command line from PHP? Isn't it easier to just call the function directly?

Comment: I tried that but I got permission errors. How would you do it? Maybe I didn't call it correctly.

Comment: permissions errors? On what? Including the `.php` file. Running the MySQL statement?

Comment: Maybe permissions errors isn't the best way to describe it. It was more difficult to get return values from the cli php file. It has a echo json_encode($data); at the end to echo out if certain things succeeded or failed, and if I tried include() it was going to add several additional steps to getting the output from the file. Since it worked when I tested it directly in the browser I figured it would work when run from the command line.

Comment: I could grab the output from the $out and $retvar in exec($cmd, $out, $retvar) very easily. I could play around with trying the include() but it will make this more complicated, and it's already pretty complicated. :)

Comment: Ok well in that case either change the function to have a return value instead of echo. If you can't do that use output buffering to capture it's output: `ob_start(); do_func(); $output = ob_get_clean();`.

Comment: It turned out the issue was caused by a line that re-established the connection to the database. I don't know why this caused all the SQL to not execute, but when I commented-out that line the command line started working.

Comment: @rapahel75 maybe it connected with different u/p?